# Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins, build, build.gradle

I am new to flutter, I had a running project and updated to the lates flutter version and upgraded one dependency. Now when I try to run the project I ge this error message:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Cannot choose between the following variants of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1:
          - javadocElements
          - sourcesElements
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Found org.gradle.category 'documentation' but wasn't required.
                  - Found org.gradle.docstype 'javadoc' but wasn't required.
                  - Required org.gradle.jvm.version '8' but no value provided.
                  - Required org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but no value provided.
                  - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
              - Compatible attributes:
                  - Required org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' and found compatible value 'external'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Found org.gradle.category 'documentation' but wasn't required.
                  - Found org.gradle.docstype 'sources' but wasn't required.
                  - Required org.gradle.jvm.version '8' but no value provided.
                  - Required org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but no value provided.
                  - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
              - Compatible attributes:
                  - Required org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' and found compatible value 'external'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
```

What the doctor says

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.9, on macOS 12.6.2 21G320 darwin-x64, locale en-AU)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.60.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Since then I cannot run my project at all, can anybody help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the build.gradle Project level set classPath

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"

    }
}
```

In the gradle-wrapper.properties set this

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped! Now I have a different issue, but this issue is solved!