# Build Gradle Error , not able run the app and error is showing when I tried gradlew signinReport

Tags: flutter

This is the error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compati
ble with Java 8
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies decl
ared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
```

I am currently trying to upgrade the Java version from 8 to 11.

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75955013/could-not-resolve-com-android-tools-buildgradle7-4-1/75955131#75955131

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75955013/could-not-resolve-com-android-tools-buildgradle7-4-1)